# Cannot read property 'toString' of undefined in Javascript

Tags: javascript, html

I know there is the method called `toString()` inside the javascript file. But I don’t understand why I get the error.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<body>
<script src="https://raw.githubusercontent.com/bradymholt/cRonstrue/master/dist/cronstrue.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
<script>
    var cronstrue = window.cronstrue;
    alert(cronstrue.toString("* * * * *"));
</script>
</body>
</html>
```

[Image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/KSS4D.png)

Comment: Will it work --> *undefined.toString()*?

Comment: @PrashantPimpale no,same error

Comment: That is what you are trying! will help if you tell us that what you want to *achive* from the posted code?

Comment: @PrashantPimpale could you answer the question with a working example?

Comment: @PrashantPimpale cron expression to human readable way. If you glance at the doc you can see https://github.com/bradymholt/cRonstrue#browser

Answer (score 3):

`https://raw.githubusercontent.com/bradymholt/cRonstrue/master/dist/cronstrue.js` is served as mimetype text/plain - so browser will not load it as javascript

However, using the documented CDN url (and removing `async`) - your code works perfectly

NOTE: the documentation includes the `async` attribute for the script - if you include that, then the code below will not work as the script won't be loaded "in time" - so, do NOT use the `async` attribute unless you know when and how to use it

```html
<script src="https://unpkg.com/cronstrue@latest/dist/cronstrue.min.js"></script>
<script>
    var cronstrue = window.cronstrue;
    console.log(cronstrue.toString("* * * * *"));
</script>
```

Answer (score 0):

Source/Link (i.e src attribute) of the external script you added is wrong as it's pointing to raw javascript which served as mime-type text/plain, not text/javascript that why the cronstrue object not getting added to window.

You can use CDN url https://unpkg.com/cronstrue@latest/dist/cronstrue.min.js, so replace the src value with cdn url.